# Excel to compare two different columns using sumifs

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have 3 columns.

First column is value
Second column is location
Third column is location

I have to sum all the values of the first column;the condition is for the same row, the location in the second column should not match with the location in the third column. In short if the locations are different, it can sum.

can this be achieved using sumifs? because there are other conditions which I can comply easily using sumifs.

Comment: Hello Charz, next time you have a question about Excel, don't hesitate to take a screenshot. AN image is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10*(B1:B10<>C1:C10))
```

[image]

You can add more criterias, not necesarry to use `SUMIF/S`